# JavaScript Internals 101: arrays are just a special type of objects

Tags: javascript

Internally, JavaScript has only objects (and primitive types). Objects are **unordered** collection of `key:value` pairs, where `key` is string and `value` can be any JavaScript type.

Arrays, though on the outside look like normal arrays of any other language, are actually a special case of objects, with natively supported language syntax.

Each array is an object where the key is a number and value can be any type. The keys are managed by JavaScript itself so that we can manipulate the array as an **ordered** collection of values. This is the reason we can use arrays in a `for-in` loop too. Additionally, JavaScript provides standard array operations (length, indexOf, splice, slice, join) as methods that take use the numbered keys to do their thing.

```
>>> typeof []
"object"

>>> Object.prototype.toString.call([])
"[object Array]"
```

Is my understanding correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: "or do I need to know more" --- for what? Are you developing your js engine?

Comment: `Is my understanding correct, or do I need to know more?` You are not incorrect, and everyone needs to know more. If you have a specific question about arrays in JS, please ask it.

Comment: I mean is my understanding right or am I missing something?

Comment: All keys are managed by JavaScript internally. Using `for...in` for arrays has the same problems as using it for objects: The order is not guaranteed. That's why one uses a `for` loop with a dedicated loop variable which *you* control and increment. If you want to learn more, I recommend to read the specification: http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.

Comment: Don't use `for-in` loop. It's can be not safe.

Comment: What does "safe" mean here?

Comment: It can iterate over properties that you did not assign yourself, which originate with a constructor. However, this is no reason to not use `for..in`, an easy workaround is to skip iterations where `obj.hasOwnProperty(keyname)` fails

Comment: Some frameworks adds functionality to builtin prototypes and you'll iterate them too. For example in some old version of IE was no indexOf method of Array, and it was  added manualy

Comment: I highly recommend reading http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#intro to learn about all the bizarre quirks of JS

Comment: Also: the `for-in` loop in `a = []; a[1] = 1; a[4] = 4; for (i in a) console.log(i);` has only 2 iterations, not 5 as one might assume. In another programming language, this would create a 5-element array where 3 values don't exist; in JS, the *indices* `0`, `2` and `3` do not exist.

Comment: Also, indices are strings, like in any object, *not* integers. Thus, `for (i in a) console.log(10 + i);` prints `101` and `104`, *not* `11` and `14`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you missed up there is that the numeric indices themselves are simply named properties of the array object, there is no underlying order to them.

Another thing that might be worth keeping in mind is that the Array constructor can be modified, which will influence all arrays from that point on.

Consider the following:

```
var a = new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
a.slice(1); // returns [2,3,4,5]

//Now for some prototype modification
Array.prototype.slice = function(){alert("Foo");};

var b = new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
a.slice(1); // alerts "Foo"!

//The [] syntax is also affected
var c = [1,2,3,4,5];
c.slice(1); // alerts "Foo"!
```

Comment: In which environment did you test the code? All arrays inherit from `Array.prototype`, it does not matter which syntax you use to create one. `c.slice(1);` alerts `Foo` too. One should avoid using the `Array` constructor because it is ambiguous and (theoretically) can be shadows/overridden.

Comment: @FelixKling You're right, I got mixed up between `Array` getting shadowed by your own identically named function and prototype modification. Thanks for the edit slebetman